# PHP fails Updating existing records

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, row

I have the following PHP Code :

```
//Selecting amount from rcpts_exp table
$query = "SELECT amount from rcpts_exp";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
    echo "FAILED";
}
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

//fetching each row
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//Simple Mathematics 
$a_b_t = $row['amount'] / 1.16;
$t = $a_b_t * 0.16;

//--------------------------------For Testing Output
//echo $row['amount']."<br />";
//echo "ABT = ". $a_b_t = number_format($a_b_t,2)."<br />";
//echo "tax = ".$t  = number_format($t,2)."<br />";
//-------------------------------End Testing

//Update the values into rcpts_exp for each amount
$query2 = "UPDATE rcpts_exp SET amount_before_tax = '".$a_b_t."', tax = '".$t."' WHERE amount = '".$row['amount']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
if(!$result2){
echo "Update Failed";
mysqli_error();
}

}
```

The "testing" part outputs the result needed perfectly, it divides the `$row['amount']` by 1.16 and the next one multiplies by 0.16.
So considering the output the correct, the problem goes towards the UPDATE section.- it might either updates the `amount_before_tax` and `tax` columns as `0.00` or skipping as default value as defined in mysql.

The Structure of my table is as follows :

- id - int(11) AI
- amount - float(10,2)
- amount_before_tax - float(10,2)
- tax - float(10,2)

Please Help!

Comment: Problem Solved by removing single quotes, thanks to Russell Kenward.

Comment: You might want to replace mysqli_error() with mysql_error(). (Not related to your problem, but might save you some trouble in the future.)

Comment: @kontrollfreak will do that, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont place single quotes around numeric fields:

Try this:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE rcpts_exp SET amount_before_tax = ".$a_b_t.", tax = ".$t." WHERE amount = ".$row['amount'];
```

Comment: Haha no problem, if I have solved your problem can you flag this post as answered :)

Comment: Yes i will, but i have to wait 5 more mins :]